# postgres 11.3 checksum validation post migration

Tags: postgresql, replication, amazon-rds, change-data-capture, checksum

I am in the process of migrating our AWS RDS postgresql from one account to another with zero downtime. I am going with pg_dump/pg_restore + AWS CDC for ongoing replication.

I am looking for a way to generate and compare checksum to make sure no differences in data or corruption.

Q1: Is it possible to generate checksum on the database level rather than table level?

Q2: OR doing a select count(*) on all the tables in source/target is better?

when there is no downtime, data changes will be coming in the source during this process and i am afraid this will affect the checksum or rowcount comparison. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

you can't achieve zero downtime migration with pg_dump.  writes that happen after the dump begins and before the restore completes and you cut-over to the new database will be lost.

What you want is log shipping, use that to build a read-only replica of thew RDS server and then cut over to that once the replica is stable.

Comment: Hi Jasen, to avoid loss of data, I am going to use CDC recovery checkpoint to replay the messages to target. Is this different than you mentioned "log shipping".  can you share some documentations for this

Answer (score 0):

If your tables have PKs (which is a requirement for CDC), then you can enable DMS validation on your CDC-only task. Here are some [AWS DMS docs][1] on their validation.
[1]: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Validating.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/198351)